# Как запускать консольные программы не указывая директорию

Tags: linux

Многие консольные программы на линуксе запускаются без указания их директории.Как сделать так же и для моих программ.

P.S. Может и на виндоус так можно?

Comment: Прописать директорию с нужными программами в переменную окружения `PATH`. И на виндоус тоже

Answer (score 2):

Просто при установке программы, сделайте так чтобы установщик по разрешению пользователя менял переменную `$PATH`, в дальнейшем соответственно при запуске вашей программы будет взят путь из переменной `$PATH`, так что на линуксе что на windows.